# Strongly Connected Components with BFS

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

How can I find strongly connected components with BFS in directed graph?

I know  Kosaraju’s algorithm which uses DFS.I want to find with BFS.

Comment: Maintain a visited array of nodes. Mark a node as visited, start BFS on that node to visit all reachable nodes. Collect all of them in a list - this list is a strongly connected component. Repeat this on all unvisited nodes.

Comment: This approach is for undirected graph not directed graph

Comment: @pouria.vzr what would make SomeDude's method fail for directed graphs ?

Comment: @dallonsi imagine a directed graph `a->b->c`. Now running BFS on `a` would visit all nodes. The graph is not strongly connected.

Answer (score 0):

A paper [[1](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1115145)] from Penn State University in 2014, proposed a multistep method, which reduced total work when compared to the forward-backward algorithm, and combined the advantages of several parallel SCC finding algorithms.

They utilized a hybrid bottom-up approach to BFS [[2](http://www.scottbeamer.net/pubs/beamer-sc2012.pdf)] and vastly reduce the total number of edge examinations needed during BFS. Different from [[2](http://www.scottbeamer.net/pubs/beamer-sc2012.pdf)], they maintained the thread queues while running the bottom-up hybrid BFS, as opposed to explicitly rebuilding the queue from scratch when switching the hybrid off, since they only required visited array to determine the SCC.

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm that uses Kosarju's BFS can be based upon the same principle of a Kosaraju's algorithm which utilizes DFS.

First, conduct a topological sort using BFS.

Next, transpose the graph.

Then traverse the graph in the topologically sorted order. Every time a traversal is finished, you have reached the end of an SCC.

The runtime of this algorithm would be O(E+V) because of the topological sort.